qfx10002-36Q sflow performance
We have two QFX10002-36Q switches, each operating as a standalone switch. Each QFX10002-36Q is handling about 280 Gbps of IMIX traffic. I want to enable sFlow/J-Flow to analyze the traffic with ElasticFlow. I would like to know if they handle sFlow/J-Flow on the ASIC. If I enable it, will it have any impact on the control plane CPU?

If you use sFlow, then this is fine.  From Juniper's own documentation [1] "You can configure sFlow technology on a device to monitor traffic continuously at wire speed on all interfaces simultaneously."
You do need to be mindful of the quantity of sFlow samples that your switch is generating, so it doesn't overwhelm either your collector or the network you reach it via (eg: if the collector is reachable via your management network interface rather than in-band with your traffic ports)
When you first configure it, start with a single interface and relatively low sample rate (eg: 1 in 5000 depending on how many PPS the interface is seeing), then measure and increase as applicable.
[1] https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/network-mgmt/topics/topic-map/sflow-monitoring-technology.html
